# How to solve this Combinatorics problem of disks and stacks?

Tags: database, algorithm, combinatorics

I have a problem that involves combinatorics that I am trying to solve in the most efficient way possible but all I keep coming up with is ways to brute force it. I was hoping I could get some suggestions on where I could look for more info or maybe how to proceed

Here is the information:
I have a list of disks with properties. These disks are categorized based on these properties. One of those properties (We'll call it Property_A) is used later on in a formula to generate a value (We'll call this Value_A).

From these disks, I have to make stacks of size N, where N is the number of disks in the stack, and each disk in the stack comes from a different category. The order of the disks in the stack matters. Disks in the same category can be swapped out for other disks with different values for Property_A to produce a new stack.

```
Example:
Stack #1 is made of the following disks
Disk #1 from Category A,
Disk #1 from Category B,
Disk #1 from Category C

I can then swap out the first Disk for Disk #2 from Category A to make a new stack (Stack #2)
Stack #2 is made of the following disks
Disk #2 from Category A,
Disk #1 from Category B,
Disk #1 from Category C
```

Once this stack is made, a formula is generated for the stack where we plug in Property_A to get Value_A. Formulas are assigned to stack types where a stack type is defined by the disk' categories

```
 Example: Only Stack #1 and Stack #2 would share the same formula because they are made from disks whos categories are in the same order

 Stack #1 is made of the following disks
    Disk #1 from Category A,
    Disk #1 from Category B,
    Disk #1 from Category C

 Stack #2 is made of the following disks
    Disk #2 from Category A,
    Disk #1 from Category B,
    Disk #1 from Category C

 Stack #3 is made of the following disks
    Disk #1 from Category B,
    Disk #1 from Category A,
    Disk #1 from Category C

 Stack #4 is made of the following disks
    Disk #1 from Category B,
    Disk #1 from Category E,
    Disk #1 from Category F
```

Here is the problem:
Given Value_A, N, and some number (We'll call it Number), find all possible stacks of size N whos Value_A is in the range

```
Value_A-Number<= Value_A<= Value_A+Number
```

I was thinking that I could use Dynamic programming to help speed this up but, given that Property_A varies greatly from Disk to Disk, I felt that I would get more misses than hits and would just end up with a solution similar in speed to brute force.

I also considered giving Property_A an upper/lower bound but that would only help with finding stacks within the same stack type. Once the stack type changed, you'd have to reset the upper/lower bound and start over.
These still seems like the most promising way to go thus far though. With this approach, I could find all possible stack type combinations, then I could narrow down the disks in the stacks using upper/lower bounds

These things aren't organized in any certain way right now, so feel free to make up assumptions about how data is organized.

Comment: Without knowing something about what the formulas look like or how they are generated, there is no optimization possible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @btilly. The formulas will be generated empirically and can be assumed to be linear equations

Comment: So, if a stack doesn't have a formula assigned to it, we can skip that stack type and just assume that it's not a viable solution